# Error "Database Logon Failed" when exporting a crystal report to pdf in .NET

Tags: iis, operating-system, crystal-reports, odbc

We have built a web service in .NET to export a crystal report to pdf and it's working as expected in Development machine but getting error "Database logon failed" once we deploy using IIS in Production server.

**Below is the code developed to export a crystal report to pdf**

```
public class CryRepWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {       
        [WebMethod]
        public string InvoiceReportCry(int Invoiceid, int docType, string Proj)
        {
            string project;
            int docTypes;
            int InvoiceIds;
            try
            {
                ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
                cryRpt.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/myreport.rpt"));
                string USERNAME = "useruser";//Default user Name
                string PWD = "pwdpwd$";//Default pwd Name
                string DSN_NAME = "mydsn";
                string INITIAL_CATALOG = "dbname";
                string serverName = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\" + DSN_NAME, "Server", null);
                cryRpt.SetDatabaseLogon(USERNAME, PWD, serverName, INITIAL_CATALOG);
                // create the connection information
                ConnectionInfo conRpt = new ConnectionInfo();
                conRpt.ServerName = serverName;
                conRpt.DatabaseName = INITIAL_CATALOG;
                conRpt.UserID = USERNAME;
                conRpt.Password =PWD;
                // apply connection information to the report tables
                Tables rptTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables;
                for (int i = 0; i < rptTables.Count; i++)
                {
                    CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table rptTable = rptTables[i];
                    TableLogOnInfo tblInfo = rptTable.LogOnInfo;
                    tblInfo.ConnectionInfo = conRpt;
                    // next table
                }
                // if the report contains sub reports, you will need to set the connection info there too
                if (cryRpt.Subreports.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < cryRpt.Subreports.Count; i++)
                    {
                        using (ReportDocument rptSub = cryRpt.OpenSubreport(cryRpt.Subreports[i].Name))
                        {
                            Tables rptTables1 = rptSub.Database.Tables;
                            for (int j = 0; j < rptTables.Count; j++)
                            {
                                CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table rptTable = rptTables1[i];
                                TableLogOnInfo tblInfo = rptTable.LogOnInfo;
                                tblInfo.ConnectionInfo = conRpt;
                                // next table
                            }
                            rptSub.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                ParameterValues crParameterValues = new ParameterValues();
                ParameterDiscreteValue crParameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
                ParameterDiscreteValue crParameterDiscreteValue1 = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
                ParameterDiscreteValue crParameterDiscreteValue2 = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
                          
                cryRpt.SetParameterValue("@Invoiceid", Invoiceid);
                cryRpt.SetParameterValue("@docType", docType);
                cryRpt.SetParameterValue("@Proj", Proj);
                project = Proj;
                docTypes = docType;
                InvoiceIds = Invoiceid;
                bool folderExists = Directory.Exists(@"D:\CrystalReports\Test_Pdf");
                if (!folderExists)
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\CrystalReports\Test_Pdf");
                cryRpt.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, @"D:\CrystalReports\Test_Pdf\test-" + Invoiceid + ".pdf");
                return project + InvoiceIds + docTypes;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionLogging.SendErrorToText(ex);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Below is the tech specifications of both environments:**

**Development System :**

```
Windows 7 Professional (64-bit)
Visual Studio 2015       Sql   
Server 2012 
ODBC Driver - Sql Server
SAP Crystal Reports 2016 (SP6) (version 14.2.6.2839)
SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework(64-bit)(version 13.0.30.3805)       
SAP Crystal Reports, version for Microsoft Visual Studio (version 13.0.30.3805)       
IIS (7.5)
```

**Production Server:**

```
  Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard (64-bit)
  Visual Studio 2015
  Sql Server 2019  
  ODBC Driver - Sql Server Native Client 10.0
  SAP Crystal Reports 2016 (SP4) (version 14.2.4.2410)  
  SAP Crystal Reports 2016 (SP9) update (version 14.2.9.3791)
  SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework(64-bit) (version 13.0.30.3805)  
  SAP Crystal Reports, version for Microsoft Visual Studio (version 13.0.30.3805)  
  IIS (8.5)
```

Please somebody help us with a solution to try.

Thanks in advance.

Maruthi A

Comment: "Database logon failed" - are the credentials for DB ok?

Comment: Yes. Moreover, verified opening the same .rpt in Crystal designer with giving parameter values and result comes as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Enable 32 bit Applications in Application Pool of IIS Server.

1. Open IIS Manager and click on Applications Pool from the Left window.
2. Right click on the Application Pool for which you want to enable 32 Bit applications and click on Advanced Settings option from the context menu.
3. In the Advanced Settings window, look for `Enable 32-Bit Applications` property, set it to True and click the OK button.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @samwu. Tried the suggested change but no change (issue still exists).

Comment: Is your ODBC datasource 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: ODBC datasource (System DSN) is 32-bit.